# show div on form option selected by user using id or class

Tags: javascript

First question here so please go easy on me ! Trying to get this form select working but after hours still struggling. Code works fine when just one option has an id, but will not work with multiple id's. Have a feeling the right approach would be to assign each select option with a class but still can't figure it out.
Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated !

```
      <form>
          <p align="center">Size : 
              <input type="hidden" value="1" name="qty1" />
              <select name="productpr1"  id="getFname" onchange="showdiv(this);">
                <option selected value="ERROR - Please select finish">please select</option>
                <option id="show" value="product 1:5:0:105805">product 1</option>
                <option id="" value="product 2:10:0:105205">product 2</option>
                <option id="show" value="product 3:15:0:105605">product 3</option>
              </select>
          </p>
          <div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;text-align:center;">Choose delivery date</div>
            <p><input type="submit" class="button" value="ADD TO BASKET" /></p>
          
        </form>

<script> 
function showdiv(nameSelect)
{
console.log(nameSelect);
if(nameSelect){
    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("show").value;
    if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}
else{
    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

**Edit**
Thanks for the assistance on here - the final version which works as I need :

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="qty1" />
      <select name="productpr1"  id="getFname" onchange="showdiv();">
        <option selected value="ERROR - Please select finish">please select</option>
        <option class="show" value="product 1:5:0:105805">product 1</option>
        <option class="" value="product 2:10:0:105205">product 2</option>
        <option class="show" value="product 3:15:0:105605">product 3</option>
      </select>
  <div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none">Choose delivery date</div>
    <p><input type="submit" class="button" value="ADD TO BASKET" /></p>
<script>
function showdiv() {
var getFname= document.getElementById("getFname");
var askForDelivery = getFname.options[getFname.selectedIndex].classList;

if(askForDelivery.contains('show')){
  document.getElementById('admDivCheck').style.display = 'block';
} 
else{document.getElementById('admDivCheck').style.display = 'none';
}}
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the form supposed to do? why is it 'not working'?

Comment: The form is to select a product, the code on the option is for pricing and SKU. I wish to use a script so if an item(s) is in stock the delivery calendar will show in the hidden div, so multiple lines may be in stock at any time.

Comment: you should not give same id,.... because id should unique

Answer (score 0):

the id property is for the object document model and should be unique, just use 1,2,3 for it

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it is not working when having multiple id's is this line here:

`admOptionValue = document.getElementById("show").value;`

That is always going to return the first element with id `show`.
You should be able to get the selected value like this:

```js
function showdiv() {
    var getFname= document.getElementById("getFname");
    var selectedValue = getFname.options[getFname.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(selectedValue);
}
```

```html
<select name="productpr1"  id="getFname" onchange="showdiv();">
        <option selected value="ERROR - Please select finish">please select</option>
        <option value="product 1:5:0:105805">product 1</option>
        <option value="product 2:10:0:105205">product 2</option>
        <option value="product 3:15:0:105605">product 3</option>
    </select>
```

So All I did was get the `selectedIndex` of the select box, rather than getting the individual option by id.  All the options should have a unique `id`, and trying to get all of them would be a huge waste of time

**EDIT**

As mentioned earlier, you wanted to add a class to a specific item to determine if it should show or hide another div.

All you would do is check for `classList` instead of `value` to determine if it is true.

All you would have to do is get the `classList` of the selected item. If it contains the desired class, show your hidden div.

```
function showdiv() {
    var getFname= document.getElementById("getFname");
    var askForDelivery = getFname.options[getFname.selectedIndex].classList;
    
    if(askForDelivery.contains('show')){
      document.getElementById('admDivCheck').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

I made a fiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/k68nuams/

Comment: You could.  If you add a class to the option, you can get the class by finding the `classList` instead of the `value`.

Answer (score 0):

In your script **admOptionValue == nameSelect.value**  This value checking will always same, because selected option only the value of select tag.....

```js
function showdiv(nameSelect)
{
 console.log('choosed option',nameSelect.value);
 if(nameSelect.value !="")   document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
 else    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p align="center">Size : 
      <input type="hidden" value="1" name="qty1" />
      <select name="productpr1"  id="getFname" onchange="showdiv(this);">
        <option selected value="">please select</option>
        <option value="product 1:5:0:105805">product 1</option>
        <option value="product 2:10:0:105205">product 2</option>
        <option value="product 3:15:0:105605">product 3</option>
      </select>
  </p>
  <div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;text-align:center;">Choose delivery date</div>
    <p><input type="submit" class="button" value="ADD TO BASKET" /></p>

</form>
```